# How to extract key based on second element of tuple key of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following data structure, where my dictionary keys are a tuple.
I want to extract the maximum of those key tuples based on it's second element.

```
dict_ = {(3,2):0.5,
        (1,5): 0.7}
```

I tried `max(dict_.keys())` which returned (3,2).

My expected output is (1, 5), which is maximum of 2 and 5, the second elements of the tuple keys. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max()` with `key` parameter:

```
max(dictp, key=lambda x: x[1])
# (1, 5)
```